# Docker-compose - Cannot connect to Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

It looks like a common issue: **can't connect to Postgres from a Django app in Docker Compose**.

Actually, I tried several solution from the web, but probably I'm missing something I cannot see.

The error I got is:

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Try again**

Where the **"db"** should be the name of the docker-compose service and which must setup in the .env.

My *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: drf_app
    volumes:
      - ./src:/drf
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 9090:8080
    env_file:
      - /.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

My *.env*:

```
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=mydb
SQL_USER=myuser
SQL_PASSWORD=mypass
SQL_HOST=db #this one should match the service name
SQL_PORT=5432
```

As far as I know, web and db should automatically see each other in the same network, but this doesn't happens.

Inspecting the ip address with ifconfig on each container: django app has *172.**17**.0.2* and the db *172.**19**.0.2*. They are not able to ping each other.

The result of docker ps command:

```
400879d47887   postgres:13-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   backend_db_1
```

I really cannot figure out the issue, so am I missing something?

Comment: Add them to same network so they'll be able to see each other https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: The Compose `links:` option is obsolete and unnecessary; does deleting it make a difference?  What specific command are you running that produces the error?  If it's a `docker-compose` command, can you tell whether it's coming from the image build or the container startup?

Comment: @PabloGrande As documented in that link, Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it.  You do not need manual `networks:` options in most common cases.

Comment: @DavidMaze removing links makes no difference. The command I run is the following:
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh backend_web -s
To enter inside the django image and then run:
python manage.py runserver
The crash happens when it tries to connect to the database which is unreacheable from a network perspective.

Comment: `docker run` doesn't use any of the settings in your `docker-compose.yml`, including the `default` network.  You shouldn't need to "enter the image" at all; just run `docker-compose up` to start the entire combined application.

Comment: I wrote a reply saying that the networking issue was related to the execution of docker-compose inside a VM, so everything was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this to save anyone in future from the same issue.

After *countless* tries, I started thinking that nothing was wrong from the pure docker perspective: I was right.

**SOLUTION**: My only suspect was related to the execution inside a **Virtual Machine**, so executing the same docker image on the host worked like a charm!
The networking issue was related to the VM (VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04)

I do not know if there is a way to work with docker-compose inside a VM, so any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment:

> The command I run is the following: `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh backend_web`

Docker Compose creates several Docker resources, including a `default` network.  If you separately `docker run` a container it doesn't see any of these resources.   The `docker run` container is on the "default bridge network" and can't use present-day Docker networking capabilities, but the `docker-compose` container is on a separate "user-defined bridge network" named `backend_default`.  That's why you're seeing a couple of the symptoms you do: the two networks have separate IPv4 CIDR ranges, and Docker's container DNS resolution only happens for the current network.

There's no reason to start a container with an interactive shell and then start your application within that (any more than you don't normally run `python` and then manually call `main()` from its REPL).  Just start the entire application:

```bash
docker-compose up -d
```

If you do happen to need an interactive shell to debug your container setup or to run some manual tasks like database migrations, you can use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) for this.  This honors most, but not all, of the settings in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  In particular you can't `docker-compose run` an interactive shell and start your application from it, since it ignores `ports:`.

```bash
# Typical use: run database migrations
docker-compose run web \
  ./manage.py migrate

# For debugging: run an interactive shell
docker-compose run web bash
```